# dynamically set property in PS

Tags: powershell

```
PS C:\> $object
Stage0         : True
Stage1         : False
Stage2         : False

PS C:\> $Stage = "Stage1"
```

is there anyway I achieve the following?

`$object.$Stage = $True` vs `$object.stage1 = $True`

Comment: $object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $Stage -Value $True -Force

Comment: Your question suggests that you want to access an _existing_ property via a variable - and the code in the question already does that -  but  the code in your comment would _create a new property_ on demand. Do you really want to create a new property, or were you using `Add-Member -Force` just as a way to set the existing property? You don't need `Add-Member` for that.